# Как добавить к одному классу второй класс с функционалом, по клику на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, json

Есть такой блок

```
<div class="big_test"></div>
```

к нему добавляется 
класс test2

```
var changephoto = document.querySelector(".changephoto");
    changephoto.onclick = function() {   
        var Bigplus = document.querySelector(".big_test");

        if(Bigplus.classList.contains("test2")) {
            Bigplus.classList.remove("test2");
        } else {
            Bigplus.classList.add("test2");
            }
    };
```

как сделать что бы при добавлении класса test2 в класс big_test, срабатывало событие onclick:

```
$('.test2').click(function(){
    $('.del_menu').addClass('active_del');
    $('.bg_del').fadeIn();
});
```

и при удалении класса test2 из класса big_test, этот функционал убирался. 
Есть идеи? Заранее Спасибо всем)

Comment: Можно вот так вот попробовать $( ".test2" ).click(); после добавления класса. Еще есть .trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам клик можно привязать к классу big_test и при клике проверять - есть ли у него test2:

```js
var bigTest = $(".big_test");

$('.changephoto').on('click', function() {  
  bigTest.toggleClass('test2');
});

var i = 0;
bigTest.on('click', function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass('test2') ){
    $(this).text( ++i ); // Не важно что... для демо.
  }
});
```

```css
.big_test {
  width: 150px; height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #123;
  background-color: #246;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test2 {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="changephoto">Change</button>
<div class="big_test"></div>
```

Решений может быть много, зависит от конечной цели.

Можете еще почитать про делегирование событий)

P.s. только fadeIn/fadeOut муторно писать на чистом JS... а так, jQuery не обязателен:

```js
var bigTest = document.querySelector(".big_test");
var changephoto = document.querySelector(".changephoto");

changephoto.addEventListener('click', function() {  
  bigTest.classList.toggle('test2');
});


var bgDel = document.querySelector(".bg_del");
var i = 0;
bigTest.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if( this.classList.contains('test2') ){
    fadeIn(bgDel);
    bgDel.innerText = ++i;
  }
});

// Пародия на fadeIn()
function fadeIn(el, time, display){
  display = display || "block";
  time = time || 1000;

  el.style.opacity = 0;
  el.style.transition = time / 1000 + 's opacity';
  el.style.display = display;

  setTimeout(function(){
    el.style.opacity = 1;
  },0);
}
```

```css
.big_test, .bg_del {
  width: 150px; height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #123;
  background-color: #246;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.bg_del { opacity: 1; display: none; }
.test2 { opacity: 1; }
```

```html
<button class="changephoto">Change</button>
<div class="big_test"></div>

<div class="bg_del"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, буду разбираться!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Ну если я правильно понял, Вы хотите прикрепить событие на класс после его добавления, при условии что у Вас уже создано событие клик на `test2`. Проблема в том когда Вы вызываете classList.add, событие клик уже прикреплена к элементам которые были созданы в DOM при загрузке страницы.

Для решения Вашей проблемы без переписывания кода (хотя можно совсем по другому сделать) Вам нужно заново повесить событие клик на элементы!,
попробуйте сделать так:

```
        var $test2 = $(".test2");
        var changephoto = document.querySelector(".changephoto");
        changephoto.onclick = function() {   
            $test2.unbind("click");
            var Bigplus = document.querySelector(".big_test");

            if(Bigplus.classList.contains("test2")) {
                Bigplus.classList.remove("test2");
            } else {
                Bigplus.classList.add("test2");
            }
            $('.test2').click(function(){
                $('.del_menu').addClass('active_del');
                $('.bg_del').fadeIn();
            });
        };
```

Comment: И тебе Спасибо!!!